# Get content of the kill-ring

Tags: emacs, elisp

So I have copied something to the ring:

```
(car kill-ring) ; #("foo" 0 4 (fontified t))
```

Then how do I get the main content this text property, namely the string `"foo"`?

Comment: You can also have a look at `(info "(emacs)Kill Ring")`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can remove all properties from a text string with `substring-no-properties`:

```
(substring-no-properties (car kill-ring))
```